# Create new MediaType via C# (For PackageAction)

Tags: c#, package, action, umbraco

I have created a package that requires the creation of an extra MediaType, since packaging it is not available in the package screens.

To circumvent this issue I've started researching into creating a new MediaType via Package Actions. Lastly started following this quick tutorial [Umbraco V7 Compatible Packages](http://24days.in/umbraco/2013/v7-packages/)

Have added a class (below), compiled it (in Debug Mode), copied it to the */bin/* folder of Umbraco, then added the dll as a package file, along with everything else.

Then, on another instance of Umbraco, installed it from local package.

Problem is: **IT IS NOT WORKING!**

At the moment I have no idea of what could be wrong, so if anyone has any suggestions, they're welcome.

Below is the class I have created:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using umbraco.interfaces;
using Umbraco.Core.Configuration;
using Umbraco.Core.Logging;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Core.Services;

namespace Social_Media_Channels.Installer
{
    public class AddMediaAction : IPackageAction
    {
        public string Alias()
        {
            return "SocialMediaChannels_AddThemes";
        }

        public bool Execute(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
        {
            string STEP = string.Empty;

            if (UmbracoVersion.Current.Major >= 7)
            {
                try
                {
                    #region MediaType
                    STEP = "Adding MediaType";
                    LogHelper.Info(typeof(AddMediaAction), STEP);
                    MediaHelper.AddMediaType();
                    #endregion

                    #region Theme Images
                    STEP = "Adding Media Themes";
                    LogHelper.Info(typeof(AddMediaAction), STEP);

                    #endregion
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var message = string.Concat("Error at install ", Alias(), " package action: " + STEP, ex);
                    LogHelper.Error(typeof(AddMediaAction), message, ex);
                    return false;
                }


            }
            return false;
        }

        public bool Undo(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
        {
            if (UmbracoVersion.Current.Major >= 7)
            {
                //MediaType mediaType = new MediaType();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public XmlNode SampleXml()
        {
            var xml = string.Format("<Action runat=\"install\" undo=\"true\" alias=\"{0}\" />", Alias());
            XmlDocument x = new XmlDocument();
            x.LoadXml(xml);
            return x;
        }


    }
}
```

Below is the Helper Class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;

namespace Social_Media_Channels.Installer
{
    public class MediaHelper
    {
        private readonly static string MediaTypeName = "Social Media Theme";

        // LogHelper.Error<TranslationHelper>("Failed to add Opening Soon localization values to language file", ex);
        public static void AddMediaType()
        {
            MediaType mediaType = new MediaType(0);
            mediaType.AllowedAsRoot = true;
            mediaType.Name = MediaTypeName;
            mediaType.Description = "Container for the Social Media Channel Theme Images";
            mediaType.IsContainer = true;

            //Allowed child nodes
            var children = new List<ContentTypeSort>
                {
                    new ContentTypeSort(1031, 0),
                    new ContentTypeSort(1032, 1)
                };

            mediaType.AllowedContentTypes = children;

            //Add properties
            var name = new PropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(-88, "themeName"));
            name.Name = "Theme Name";
            name.Description = "Name for the theme";

            var url = new PropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(-88, "themeUrl"));
            url.Name = "Theme Url";
            url.Description = "Url for the original theme";

            var createdBy = new PropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(-88, "createdBy"));
            createdBy.Name = "Created By";
            createdBy.Description = "Theme Author";

            var createdDate = new PropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(-41, "createdDate"));
            createdDate.Name = "Created Date";
            createdDate.Description = "Date the Theme was created";

            mediaType.AddPropertyType(name, "Image");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(url, "Image");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(createdBy, "Image");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(createdDate, "Image");
        }

        public static void RemoveMediaType()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And in Package Actions (Umbraco) I have added the following line

```
<Action runat="install" undo="true" alias="SocialMediaChannels_AddThemes" />
```

**Suggestions or corrections? Anyone?**

Comment: Can you tell us what the errors are or how it's not working?  Some sort of context on this would be helpful.  Also, have you attempted to debug the package installation locally?

Comment: One important thing to notice is that the new _Umbraco.Core.Media.MediaType_ does not have a `Save()` method... so I'm guessing that was why it was not saving. Ended up using the Obsolete version of the MediaType and it works now (see my answer below)

Comment: You need to use the MediaTypeService.Save() instead.  None of the actual object models have a Save method anymore.  Refer to the Services documentation: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Management/Services/

Comment: Yes, it took me a lot of digging to figure that one out. Coming from version 6 has a small learning curb :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were a lot of things wrong with my original code. Finally got it working after lots of investigation.

Basically the Adding (which was causing it to fail) became:

```
    public static void AddMediaType()
    {
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType(-1);
        mediaType.AllowedAsRoot = true;
        mediaType.Name = NAME;
        mediaType.Description = "Container for the Social Media Channel Theme Images";
        mediaType.IsContainer = true;
        mediaType.Icon = "icon-picture";
        mediaType.Alias = ALIAS;

        //Allowed child nodes
        var children = new List<ContentTypeSort>
            {
                new ContentTypeSort(FOLDER_ID, 0),
                new ContentTypeSort(IMAGE_ID, 1)
            };

        mediaType.AllowedContentTypes = children;
        DataTypeService dataTypeService = (DataTypeService)ApplicationContext.Current.Services.DataTypeService;


        //Add properties
        var name = new PropertyType(dataTypeService.GetDataTypeDefinitionById(TEXT_ID), "themeName");
        name.Name = "Theme Name";
        name.Description = "Name for the theme";
        name.SortOrder = 0;

        var url = new PropertyType(dataTypeService.GetDataTypeDefinitionById(TEXT_ID), "themeUrl");
        url.Name = "Theme Url";
        url.Description = "Url for the original theme";
        url.SortOrder = 1;

        var createdBy = new PropertyType(dataTypeService.GetDataTypeDefinitionById(TEXT_ID), "createdBy");
        createdBy.Name = "Created By";
        createdBy.Description = "Theme Author";
        createdBy.SortOrder = 2;

        var createdDate = new PropertyType(dataTypeService.GetDataTypeDefinitionById(DATE_ID), "createdDate");
        createdDate.Name = "Created Date";
        createdDate.Description = "Date the Theme was created";
        createdDate.SortOrder = 3;

        mediaType.AddPropertyType(name, "Image");
        mediaType.AddPropertyType(url, "Image");
        mediaType.AddPropertyType(createdBy, "Image");
        mediaType.AddPropertyType(createdDate, "Image");

        ContentTypeService contentTypeService = (ContentTypeService)ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentTypeService;
        contentTypeService.Save(mediaType);
    }
```

And now it works!

Answer (score 0):

By comparing with the DAMP source code ([DAMP](http://damp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#DAMP.Samples/Installer.ascx.cs)) I noticed that the new MediaType class *Umbraco.Core.Models.MediaType* is missing the `Save()` method, so no matter how I tested, it simply would not save the new media type.

Anyway, also by using DAMP's example (good old copy/paste), that uses the old assemblies and shows a message **'OBSOLETE'**, came up with a new version of the code, which worked as expected.

What the code with the old libraries looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.controls;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.packager.standardPackageActions;
using umbraco.DataLayer;
using umbraco.interfaces;
using umbraco.IO;

namespace SocialMediaChannels
{
    public class AddSocialMediaThemes : IPackageAction
    {
        private readonly static string MediaTypeName = "Social Media Theme";
        private readonly static int LABEL_ID = -92;
        private readonly static int UPLOAD_ID = -90;
        private readonly static int TEXT_ID = -88;
        private readonly static int DATE_ID = -41;
        private readonly static int IMAGE_ID = 1031;
        private readonly static int FOLDER_ID = 1032;

        public IDataType uploadField = new Factory().GetNewObject(new Guid("5032a6e6-69e3-491d-bb28-cd31cd11086c"));


        protected static ISqlHelper SqlHelper
        {
            get
            {
                return umbraco.BusinessLogic.Application.SqlHelper;
            }
        }
        public string Alias()
        {
            return "SocialMediaChannels_AddSocialMediaThemes";
        }

        public bool Execute(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
        {
            bool flag;

            try
            {
                #region MediaType
                User adminUser = new User(0);

                MediaType theme = CreateMediaType(adminUser, MediaTypeName);

                MediaType folder = MediaType.GetByAlias("Folder");

                int[] folderStructure = folder.AllowedChildContentTypeIDs;
                int newsize = folderStructure.Length + 1;

                Array.Resize(ref folderStructure, newsize);
                folderStructure[newsize - 1] = theme.Id;

                folder.AllowedChildContentTypeIDs = folderStructure;

                MediaType image = MediaType.GetByAlias(MediaTypeName);


                #endregion

                #region Theme Images
                #endregion

                flag = true;
            }
            catch
            {

                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;

        }

        public bool Undo(string packageName, XmlNode xmlData)
        {
            bool flag;
            try
            {
                //remove themes
                flag = true;
            }
            catch
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            return flag;
        }

        public XmlNode SampleXml()
        {
            string sample = string.Format("<Action runat=\"install\" undo=\"true/false\" alias=\"{0}\" ></Action>", Alias());
            return helper.parseStringToXmlNode(sample);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a Media Type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="adminUser"></param>
        /// <param name="mediaTypeName"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private MediaType CreateMediaType(User adminUser, string mediaTypeName)
        {
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.MakeNew(adminUser, mediaTypeName);
            int[] typeIds =  { FOLDER_ID, IMAGE_ID };
            mediaType.AllowAtRoot = true;
            mediaType.Text = MediaTypeName;
            mediaType.Description = "Container for the Social Media Channel Theme Images";
            mediaType.IsContainerContentType = true;
            mediaType.AllowedChildContentTypeIDs = typeIds;

            //Add properties
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(UPLOAD_ID), "umbracoFile", "Upload image");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(LABEL_ID), "umbracoWidth", "Width");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(LABEL_ID), "umbracoHeight", "Height");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(LABEL_ID), "umbracoBytes", "Size");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(LABEL_ID), "umbracoExtension", "Type");

            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(TEXT_ID), "themeName", "Name of the Social Channel Theme");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(TEXT_ID), "themeUrl", "Url for the Theme");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(TEXT_ID), "createdBy", "Author of the Theme");
            mediaType.AddPropertyType(new DataTypeDefinition(DATE_ID), "createdDate", "Date the Theme was created");

            mediaType.Text = mediaTypeName;
            mediaType.IconUrl = "mediaPhoto.gif";
            mediaType.Save();

            return mediaType;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Action looks like this

```
<Action runat="install" undo="true" alias="SocialMediaChannels_AddSocialMediaThemes" ></Action>
```